# Saving data via AJAX, once done only then redirect the user

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, redirect

I am working on a form which is saved via ajax, this part is working perfectly fine. The problem I am having is user looses the data when before saving the form he clicks on another link which redirects the user to another page.

As a solution, I thought of using JavaScript function so `onclick` of hyperlink I am prompting the user to save the data before moving on. I am utilizing the same function that saves the data via AJAX and upon successful saving redirect the user. This is what my prompt looks like.

```
function saveThenRedirect(redirect) {
    if (confirm("Please save your data before moving away") == true) {
        update();// AJAX function that saves the data
        window.location = redirect;//redirect the user
    } else {
        window.location = redirect;
    }
}
```

The thing is before the `update()`; function gets the chance to save the data, user gets redirected or while it is in process of saving the redirection takes place. So this is what I need help in, what can i do to run the `update()` function first and only once it is done running redirect the user?

Note: I did look into `window.onbeforeunload` but i decided to go with a simple prompt and then use function to save and redirect.

This is what my `update` function looks like

```
function update() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "classes/data.class.php",
        data: $("#pay-form").serialize(),
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#dvloader').show();
        },
        success: function (html) {
            var load1 = new $.Deferred();
            var load2 = new $.Deferred();
            var load3 = new $.Deferred();
            var load4 = new $.Deferred();

            $.when(load1, load2, load3, load4).then(function () {
                $('#dvloader').hide();
            });

            $('#income-expense-div').load('dashboard-sidebar.php', function () {
                load1.resolve();
            });
            $('#pay-div').load('dashboard-pay.php', function () {
                load2.resolve();
            });
            $('#assets-div').load('dashboard-assets.php', function () {
                load3.resolve();
            });
            $('#liabilities-div').load('dashboard-liabilities.php', function () {
                load4.resolve();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I will really appreciate any help.

**Please note that `update` is the SAME function being used with Save button (where redirection is not required). If I add the redirect inside ajax success call the user will get redirected. This redirect is ONLY needed if user clicks on another link, so the saving needs to take place first and then redirection**

Comment: Depending on how you're implementing your AJAX requests and what frameworks you're using (if any), you can add a "success" handler that executes only when the request completes successfully, in which you could redirect the user. If you showed us the bare-bones of your AJAX implementation, we could help you more specifically to your case.

Comment: Can you share your update function ?

Comment: If `update()` is an asynchronous operation then you're executing the next line (the redirect) right away and ignoring the AJAX operation.  You need to execute that *in response to* the asynchronous operation.  Depending on how you make your AJAX call, this can be structured in a few different ways.

Comment: What you are looking for is called a 'callback' function, a function that is called when another function completes. This allows you to chain application events together. A framework like jQuery includes this and makes it very easy to use.

Comment: I am using jQuery and I have updated my question with `update` function. Please note that this is the SAME function being used with `Save` button. If I add the redirect inside ajax call the user will get redirect. This redirect is ONLY needed if user clicks on another link, so the saving needs to take place first and then redirection

Comment: Well, check on `beforeSend` and redirect on `success`

Comment: @Mark, I thought I have the AJAX call that is saving the data, so I decided to use the same AJAX call to save and then redirect.

Comment: @hex494D49 Please note that `update` is the SAME function being used with Save button (where redirection is not required). If I add the redirect inside ajax success call the user will get redirected. This redirect is ONLY needed if user clicks on another link, so the saving needs to take place first and then redirection

Comment: I see. You could have a hidden field with a default value = 0; then check this value when the user leaves the site `if(form.flag.value === 0){update();redirect();}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a variable to your code, in the update function:

```
// Adding a redirect variable...
function update( redirect ) {
```

And then inside the success function, check for the redirect variable...

```
success: function (html) {

    // Other code here

    if(redirect == true) {
        saveThenRedirect();
    }
}
```

And then when you call update from the save button:

```
update( false );
```

Or from the Redirect option:

```
update( true );
```

Alternatively you can wrap the update function in another call or further abstract the two calls, but this works well enough in this case. Probably you should have two functions instead of one and they should call additional functions as needed.

Answer (score 1):

create an Hyperlink like

```
<a data-href="url" href="javascript:void(0)" id="submitForm">Submit</a>
```

Bind onclick event like this

```
$("#submitForm").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // store url in a variable
    var url=$(this).data("href");

    // create a callback in update() function which will be called when ajax request completes
    update(function(){
    // now redirect the user
     window.location = url;
    });

});
```

Add a callback in your function like this

```
function update(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "classes/fact-find-data.class.php",
            data: $("#pay-form").serialize(),
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#dvloader').show();
            },
            success: function (html) {
           ...............................
            in the end
            callback();
          }
    });
}
```

Comment: This `update` function is using used at two places, 1) with save button (redirection should not take place with this button) 2) when the user clicks on any link to move away from website, i am calling the same `update` function to save the data first and then using `window.location` to redirect. Please have a look at the note in bold in my question

Comment: you can pass parameters for that. That is not a big issue